# Knockout writable computed observables, creating a timer

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to create an writable computable observable in knockoutjs, I almost have it done but it is unable to read the computed value. Am I doing something wrong?

```
this.time_remaining = ko.computed({
    read: function() {
        return this.time_remaining; <!-- Does this need setInterval? -->
    },
    write: function() {
        window.setInterval(function() {
            this.time_remaining = moment('2015-09-14').countdown().toString();
            console.log(this.time_remaining) 
           <!-- The console shows a timer, that is exciting! -->
        }, 1000)

    },
    owner: this
});
```

However, it is still unable to read the value in the data-bind and it is not working correctly. Perhaps I am doing it completely wrong.

```
<h4 data-bind="text: time_remaining" class="timer"></h4>
```

Comment: You need another property to act as the backing variable. Right now it looks like you're returning the computed as the value and the write is overriding the computed.

Answer (score 0):

You need a backing variable for your computed.

```
this.time;
this.time_remaining = ko.computed({
    read: function() {
         return this.time;
   } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

*You don't need a writeable computed for a timer*. You can just change a regular observable on the interval:

```js
var ViewModel = function(countDownTo) { 
  var self = this;
  
  self.time_remaining = ko.observable();
  
  var updateCountdown = function() {
    var diff = moment.duration(countDownTo - moment());
    var textDiff = diff.hours() +":"+ diff.minutes() +":"+ diff.seconds();
    self.time_remaining(textDiff);
  };
  
  window.setInterval(updateCountdown, 1000);
  updateCountdown();
};

var then = moment().add(10, 'h'); // Fake it!

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(then));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<h4 data-bind="text: time_remaining" class="timer"></h4>
```

Some other points of interest:

- Use the `var self = this;` idiom to make `this` cleanly accessible in callbacks such as `updateCountdown` or writeable computeds;
- Define the callback for setInterval seperately (a) so you can unit test it if you expose it and (b) so that you can call it a first time too and not wait 1000 ms for it to start;

I *can* see the value of a *read only* computed if you want to disallow sneaky updates of the observable:

```
var ViewModel = function(countDownTo) { 
  var self = this;
  var my_time_remaining = ko.observable();

  var updateCountdown = function() {
    var diff = moment.duration(countDownTo - moment());
    var textDiff = diff.hours() +":"+ diff.minutes() +":"+ diff.seconds();
    my_time_remaining(textDiff);
  };

  self.time_remaining = ko.computed(function() { return my_time_remaining(); });

  window.setInterval(updateCountdown, 1000);
  updateCountdown();
};
```

Or this equivalent:

```
  self.time_remaining = ko.computed(my_time_remaining);
```

If you really *do* want or need a writeable computed, remember, [this is the format](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-writable.html):

```
self.myComputed = ko.computed({
  read: function() {
    // Parameterless function, returning the value of an internal 
    // variable, perhaps dependent on another observable to trigger
    // automatic UI updates
  },
  write: function(newValue) {
    // Note the `newValue` parameter that's being passed from a
    // caller (the UI, a interval callback, etc).
  }
});
```